# Use a bond interface like a bridge

Tags: networking, bridge, bonding

I was trying to set up a bridged interface in Micro Core Linux. There's no bridge available in the kernel.So now I would like to know if there's easy way to use a bond like a bridge?

Answer (score 1):

Bonding is aggregating multiple interfaces together to form one virtual interface between the same two devices (e.g. servers or switches). Bridging is layer 2 packet forwarding between multiple ethernet interfaces (like a switch does). They are not the same thing and you certainly can't use one as if it were the other.

Comment: Since I'm using it for generating pcap data I would still get the same output if I use a bond instead of a bridge. At least I thinck so.

Comment: No. You need a link partner that also speaks the bonding protocol in order to properly create a bond interface.